# AngularJS child controller binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am including a view using the ngInclude directive. The included view has properties that binds values to `$scope.model`. This is a problem, since the parent scope is using `$scope.model`. What i need to do is to "reroute" the included views `$scope.model` to the parent scope's property `$scope.include1.model`. How can i do this "scope reroute" the way i want to?

Here is an example showing my problem

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'input.html'"></div>

    <div ng-include="'input.html'"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="input.html">
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="model"/>
    </div>
</script>
```

As you can see i have two includes to the same view, and both input text boxes will be bound to the same value. I want to bind them to different values in `myCtrl`

I can't make any changes to either my childCtrl or the included view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div ng-include="'input.html'" ng-init='model=include1.model'></div>
<div ng-include="'input.html'" ng-init='model=include2.model'></div>
```